# Implementing Microsoft Azure AD Single Sign-On in .NET 4.8 Web Forms Application with C#5

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, webforms, single-sign-on

I have a web application built using the .NET 4.8 framework and C#5. It's hosted on a Windows Server 2019 through IIS, and we currently use email and password for authentication. However, I'm looking to add a single sign-on (SSO) option using Microsoft Azure AD.

I've already created the application in Azure and completed the app registration process. I've also considered creating a separate .NET application for authentication and publishing it to IIS, but I'm not sure if that's the correct approach since I have only one application.

Could someone guide me on the standard and best practice for implementing SSO through Microsoft Azure AD in my existing .NET 4.8 Web Forms application? I want to support both traditional login and Microsoft Azure AD single sign-on. Any help or sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to go through the documentation, there are plenty of samples online on Microsoft's website. Try something and then when you face a problem, come back with a technical question. This question, as is, is not appropriate for this forum. Have a look a the [Help Section](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of outdated information for AzureAD and .net 4.72/8 As far as implementing both I've found that using .net FormsAuthentication and SSO can conflict.  You will be writing custom code to check for a web.config more than likely.  I'd recommend just going with one form or the other. However, if you just want to get SSO up and running in 4.8 I'd recommend this tutorial from Microsoft.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/msgraph-build-aspnetmvc-apps/3-exercise-create-app

This uses OWIN Middleware and a web.config for configuration. This is nice because then you don't have to figure out how to add appsettings.json to your ASP.Net project.

Comment: Thank you for the link it looks similar to what I am searching for. I will read that documentation and start from there.